# typescript for duplicate validation

Tags: string, typescript, class, boolean

Why have to add string before boolean and why they are link together for check duplicate validation

```
Checkduplicate($name: string) : boolean {
  for (let a of this.dataarray) {
    if (a['haha'].Name === $name) {return true;}
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why have to add string before boolean

`string` tells us that parameter `$name` must be of type string

> why they are link together for check duplicate validation

Not sure what you mean, but this function checks if the `string` `$name` has duplicates in `this.dataarray`

Comment: You are welcome! Consider also upvoting and selecting my answer as best, because this is how you thank people on SO.